# Does the level rating after a battle affect anything?

Tags: front-mission-3

After every battle, you are given a rating such as silver, gold, platnium.  Does this affect anything in game?

Comment: I believe the Platinum medals unlock boss type enemies (like the big Heidong 3, in Nanjing with 40 medals) on the Real Battle setting for most simulators. Not sure about the others. Platinums are easy to get.

Comment: @krazer is there any way of going back to earn some or am I SOL if I missed any

Comment: It's been a while since I picked this game up. I remember that if you save the game as soon as you start a battle, you can reload and try again if you don't get the desired results (and skip the cut scenes). I think you can replay again in New Game+ while retaining you battle skills. I don't think you can go back and select specific battle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a certain point in the storyline, when you get at least 30 (I don't remember exactly) platinum medals, you get access to a secret Wanzer. However, that Wanzer is also accessible by other means. So basically platinum medals serve no purpose other than giving you bragging rights.

Answer (score 0):

The code and access to the dialer that gives you the secret Wanzer are available once you finish a certain number of battles (some FAQ's have that number, iirc), whether you get Platinum medals or not.  Sometimes the wanzer *does* appear sooner as a bonus opponent -- and can possibly be captured that way!  **It would make sense that number of Platinum medals is the deciding factor on it appearing sooner**, but based on when that wanzer has appeared (I've done multiple playthroughs of each storyline) I suspect the number is more like 40 than 30.  Still working on doing an all-platinum game, which is NOT easy!